# How can I create a shortcut to another block of code within a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Alright, so I have to design a currency converter for my final project in this class I have. So far, I've gotten the if statements for the options of the currency the user is converting from. But the issue is, I'm not sure how to create if statements for the second currency the user converts to, without having to paste large and messy amounts of code into each if statement of the first options.

I've tried a little to create another function with what I need in it, but I'm unsure if I can or how I can call it back within the original function.

Also, with the currency code thing, I'm planning to create while loops below it, so it asks the user, then converts it based on how much the code is; different amounts are reserved for different currencies.

```
function CurrencyConverter(){
    var cad = "CAD";
    var usd = "USD";
    var gbp = "GBP";
    var euro = "EUR";
    var yen = "JPY";
    var CurrencyCode = 0;
    var inputted_currency = prompt("What currency is your amount in?");

    if(inputted_currency == cad || inputted_currency == "Canadian" || inputted_currency == "Canadian Dollars"){
        CurrencyCode + 1;
        document.getElementById("FromCurrency").innerHTML = "CAD";
        var twoC = call(SecondCurrency);
    } 

    else if(inputted_currency == usd || inputted_currency == "American" || inputted_currency == "American Dollars"){
        CurrencyCode + 2;
        document.getElementById("FromCurrency").innerHTML = "USD";
        var converted_currency = prompt("What currency would you like to convert to?");
    }

    else if(inputted_currency == gbp || inputted_currency == "British" || inputted_currency == "British Pounds" || inputted_currency == "Pounds"){
        CurrencyCode + 3;
        document.getElementById("FromCurrency").innerHTML = "GBP";
        var converted_currency = prompt("What currency would you like to convert to?");
    }

    else if(inputted_currency == euro || inputted_currency == "European" || inputted_currency == "European Euros" || inputted_currency == "Euros"){
        CurrencyCode + 4;
        document.getElementById("FromCurrency").innerHTML = "EUR";
        var converted_currency = prompt("What currency would you like to convert to?");
    }

    else if(inputted_currency == yen || inputted_currency == "Japanese" || inputted_currency == "Japanese Yen" || inputted_currency == "Yen"){
        CurrencyCode + 5;
        document.getElementById("FromCurrency").innerHTML = "JPY";
        var converted_currency = prompt("What currency would you like to convert to?");
    }

    else if(inputted_currency == "Dollars"){
        var dollar = prompt("Alright, Canadian or American?");

        if (dollar == "American"){
            CurrencyCode + 2;
            document.getElementById("FromCurrency").innerHTML = "USD";
            var converted_currency = prompt("What currency would you like to convert to?");
        }

        else if(dollar == "Canadian"){
            CurrencyCode + 1;
            document.getElementById("FromCurrency").innerHTML = "CAD";
            var converted_currency = prompt("What currency would you like to convert to?");
        }

        else{alert("Sorry, that's not a valid option. Please enter either American or Canadian exactly")
                }       
    }

    else{alert("Sorry, that's not one of the supported currencies")

 }

}
```

The end product, that I'm hoping for, is that once the user clicks a button, they input the currencies they're converting from and to, as well as the amount they have in that currency. Then the converter is able to display different amounts based on what the currencies they put in are, as well as their amount.

If I could get any tips to streamline my code at all, or somehow link the main code to another a block of code, I'd appreciate it. Thank you for your time thus far.

Comment: you'd be better off with a dropdown list of currencies instead of asking for text-based input and then trying to guess what the user meant. And then you need to employ an array listing the currencies and conversion rates to every other currency, so you can just do a lookup and get the necessary value (instead of having hundreds of if statements). P.S. not sure what you mean by "link the code to another block of code" - are you talking about calling another function, perhaps?

Comment: what is `call` doing? what is `CurrencyCode + 1;` supposed to do? for changing a value, you need an assignment operator, like `=` or `+=`.

Comment: maybe you consider to convert the string after getting to lower case and test against with lower case strings. then take a while loop until a string is correctly identified as a valid currency. so basically to get two currencies, you ight use a function just for entering and checking and returning this value. mabe take a parameter for the diplayed string, like *first* or *second* currency.

Comment: Yeah the call thing was me messing around trying to call it back somehow. The currency code is what I'm planning to use in a separate while loop that asks the user their amount and converts it based on the currency code, for example: while (currencycode == 12){ -prompt amount? -amount * specific rate}

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd benefit greatly from putting some of this information into two Objects; one for storing user selections (country, amount, and target country), and another that maps out the user input to country info.

```
var userInput = {
    countryFrom: null,
    amount: null,
    countryTo: null
};
var countryMapping: {
    'Canadian':{
        CurrencyCode: 1,
        countryCode: 'CAD',
    },
    'Canadian Dollars':{
        CurrencyCode: 1,
        countryCode: 'CAD',
    },
    //...repeat for all mappings
};

function currencyConverter(){
       // first prompt
       var inputted_currency = prompt("What currency is your amount in?");
       if(countryMapping.hasOwnProperty(inputted_currency)){
           var result = countryMapping[inputted_currency];
           var countryCode = result.countryCode;
           document.getElementById("FromCurrency").innerHTML = countryCode;
           //var CurrencyCode = result.CurrencyCode;
           userInput.countryFrom = countryCode;

           // second prompt
           var converted_currency = prompt("What currency would you like to convert to?");
           if(countryMapping.hasOwnProperty(converted_currency)){
               var secondResult = countryMapping[converted_currency];
               var countryCode = secondResult.countryCode;
               //var CurrencyCode = secondResult.CurrencyCode;
               userInput.countryTo = secondResult.countryCode;
           } else {
               alert("Sorry, that's not one of the supported currencies")
           }
       } else {
           alert("Sorry, that's not one of the supported currencies")
       }
}
```

This doesn't handle getting the amount from the user. Also I didn't deal with the CountryCode, which as other users have mentioned doesn't do anything  if it isn't assigned into a variable.

Comment: Was going to suggest him to use objects myself. It'll be cleaner and way more maintainable that way.